# Python : Change dtype of dask array

Tags: python, dask

Below is a dask array

```
>>> import dask.array as da
>>> x = da.random.normal(5,2,size=(3,3),chunks=(1,1))
>>> x
dask.array<da.rand..., shape=(3, 3), dtype=float64, chunksize=(1, 1)>
```

I want to change dtype to float96 of `x`. How to do?

Answer (score 2):

Usually you can use the `.astype(...)` method to change the dtype of a NumPy or Dask array.

```
x = x.astype(...)
```

However, unfortunately neither NumPy nor Dask.array supports `float96`

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.float
np.float     np.float16   np.float64   np.floating  
np.float128  np.float32   np.float_    

In [2]: np.array(1, dtype='float96')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-50670c2e1bb5> in <module>()
----> 1 np.array(1, dtype='float96')

TypeError: data type "float96" not understood
```

Comment: Thanks. But 'float' support is machine dependent. As you can see by "np.float" your machine will not support float96, float128 will work on your machine.